# What is the version of Akka Streams that Play 2.5 uses?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream

> From version 2.5, Play’s default stream processing library is Akka
>   Streams.

I cannot find the official docs anywhere and I'm wondering what exactly is the Akka Stream version that `Play 2.5` uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Play 2.5.x uses Akka 2.4.20](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/project/Dependencies.scala#L9):

```
object Dependencies {

  val akkaVersion = "2.4.20"
  ...
  val streamsDependencies = Seq(
    "org.reactivestreams" % "reactive-streams" % "1.0.0",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
  ...
}
```